# Set the prototype constructor correctly on an object

Tags: javascript

I have a DTO type that really is a map of key/value pairs. I would typically use an object literal for this for terseness, but this preculdes the resulting object having the `[[prototype]].constructor` set to a meaningful value.

e.g.

```
function MyDto() {
    var o = { 
        myProperty: null
    };

    return o; //[[prototype]].constructor is meaningless
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar, but have the `[[prototype]].constructor` property set to the more meaningful `MyDto` (instead of `Object`)?

Comment: What do you want it set as?

Comment: What do you mean by "set correctly"?

Comment: I would like `o.[[prototype]].constructor` to be set to point to `MyDto`.

Comment: Something like this: `function MyDto() { return { constructor: MyDto, myProperty: null }; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very much sure what you want to do. But this may help..

```
function MyDto() {
    var o = { 
        myProperty: null
    }; 
    Object.setPrototypeOf(o,MyDto.prototype);
    return o;
}

a = MyDto();
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. I wondered if there was an approach avoiding the "strongly discouraged" (acc to Mozilla) `Object.setPrototypeOf`. I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

To make `obj instanceof Foo` work, the prototype of `obj` has to point to the value of the `prototype` property of the function (`Foo`). A couple of ways have already been suggested, here is another one:

Call the function with `new` and return `this` (implicitly or explicitly). If you want to be able to call the function without `new` (not really clear from your question), check inside the function whether it was called with `new` or not:

```
function MyDto() {
    if (!(this instanceof MyDto)) {
        return new MyDto();
    }
    Object.assign(this, {myProperty: null});
}
```

---

**Note:** The `constructor` property has no meaning internally, only to the developers using your code.

Comment: Wouldn't `function MyDto() { if (this instanceof MyDto) this.myProperty = null; else return new MyDto; }` be better?

Comment: In my humble opinion, `if (!(this instanceof MyDto))` looks uncouth. In addition, it has an extra `!` operation which is unnecessary. Just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand your question, but you might try this:

```
o.constructor = MyDto;
```

This will set `o`'s constructor as `MyDto`, but will have no effect when doing `o instanceof MyDto`.

If this is what you want, my suggest is that you instantiate MyDto instead:

```
function MyDto() {
    this.myProperty = null;
}

var o = new MyDto();
console.log(o instanceof MyDto);       // true
console.log(o.constructor === MyDto);  // true
```

**EDIT:** If you `return` within a function, then you will lost the reference to your `new` instance. In your case `MyDto` works as a factory to instances of `Object` that have an own property called `myPropert`.

**EDIT 2:** I still prefer the other way, but using `Object.create` also works:

```
function MyDto() {
    return Object.create(MyDto.prototype, {
        myProperty: {
            writable: true,
            configurable: true,
            value: null
        }
    });
}

new MyDto() instanceof MyDto;       // true
new MyDto().constructor === MyDto;  // true
```

Comment: This is not what I want. Instead, I would like `new MyDto() instanceof MyDto` to return true whilst using the object literal approach for terseness.

Comment: If you return within a function, then it will behave like a function, even if you called with new. Not completely true, but I see your point. My question is - can I construct the code in the question to set the constructor property on the [[prototype]] of the returned object to MyDto, whilst retaining the object literal notation.

Answer (score 0):

You're approaching this from the wrong direction. If you want the result of `new Class()` be a real `instanceof Class`, just extend the default instance object, instead of creating and returning a new one.

```
function Class () {
    _.extend(this, {
        property: 'value',
        // ...
    });
}
```

*(The above code uses [Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) function `_.extend()` to keep your code short & sweet. Similar implementations may be found in almost all utility libraries or bigger JavaScript frameworks).*